# Problems with resizing images in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, image

"Does anyone know the reason for this distortion in the image resolution? I'm using `Image.network`, and I changed the image quality to 'medium,' and it worked perfectly on Android and iOS. However, the problem persists on Flutter web via Chrome."
[image]

I use the property to set a cache, but this also work only mobile

Comment: Have you tried toggling with the web renderer options? Use either  "flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html" or "flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit" and see the changes if any.

Comment: thanks! the command `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html` made it work perfectly in the development environment, but in deploy it still has an error. I'm running the command:
`flutter build web --web-renderer html --release --web-renderer=auto`
Do you have any more tips?

Comment: maybe,  --web-renderer=auto is no more required as you have already mentioning the option as html

Comment: thank you so much for you attention. But the problem continues to deploy on firebase hosting

Comment: You should optimise your images for web. There are google owned tools that optimises web images by uploading to Google server. I believe those are safe and better